# what is the proper way to connect to a WebSocketGateway server in Nestjs production mode?

Tags: socket.io, nestjs-gateways

my nestjs WebSocketGateway server is working perfectly in dev mode but in production mode i can see those clients that trying to connect but the server raise the followed exception `2022-02-08T08:33:33.901Z  undefined   ERROR   No exports found in module "../dist/main.js". 2022-02-08T08:33:33.901Z    undefined   ERROR   Did you forget to export a function or a server? RequestId: 9186e127-dbdd-4a1a-988c-dbfa0521b37c Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1 Runtime.ExitError`.

here my code
`import { SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway, WebSocketServer, } from '@nestjs/websockets'; import { Server } from 'socket.io'; @WebSocketGateway({ transports: ['websocket', 'polling'], cors: { origin: '*', methods: ['GET', 'POST'], } }) export class EventsGateway { @WebSocketServer() server: Server;`

and my module here

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventsGateway } from './events.gateway';

@Module({
providers: [EventsGateway],
})
export class EventsModule {}.
```

and then my main.ts

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '900mb' }));
app.use(
bodyParser.urlencoded({
limit: '900mb',
extended: true,
}),
);
app.enableCors({
origin: function (origin, callback) {
if (!origin || allowed.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
callback(null, true)
} else {
callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
}
},
});
await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
console.log(`your app is running on ${await app.getUrl()}`)
```

here the server endpoint const ENDPOINT 'https://backendsejour.vercel.app/';
and here how i use to connect to it, localy it work but production not
export const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@WebSocketGateway({ cors: true })` in your `gateway` module.
This method worked for me.